# Enable Mouse Integration between Real OS and Virtual OS without coding

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, mouse, integration

I have a virtual machine that had been build in Vbox.
My Laptop OS is Windows and I build vm with Ubuntu OS in Vbox 4.3.4.

One day, I update my vbox to 4.3.6 version.
After that, I don't know why, I should press right control button in order to move my mouse from Real OS to Virtual OS and conversely.

I found from several forum that I should make change to the configuration file like this:

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe
```

and then add these lines into it:

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier "Configured Mouse"
    Driver "vboxmouse"
    Option "CorePointer"
EndSection
```

Furthermore, I should restart my virtual machine afterward.

In this case, Is there any easier way to enable mouse integration?

Thanks

Comment: I come to a curiosity. Shall we reinstall the Vbox guest addition when we update the Vbox version?

Comment: That would be a very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Re-install **Vbox Guest Addition** after updating **Vbox** will be one alternative solution.